# Brave snap only recognizes yubikey after re-inserting it

Tags: snap, brave, yubikey

Really annoying, but my brave (snap) install will only use my yubikey after I re-insert it after starting brave.

Chrome (installed as deb) works flawless, so I assume it has *something* to do with the snap.

The snap connections seem fine (u2f-devices):

```
audio-playback            brave:audio-playback            :audio-playback                 -
audio-record              brave:audio-record              :audio-record                   -
bluez                     brave:bluez                     :bluez                          -
browser-support           brave:browser-sandbox           :browser-support                -
camera                    brave:camera                    :camera                         -
content                   brave:foo-install-cups          -                               -
content[gnome-42-2204]    brave:gnome-42-2204             gnome-42-2204:gnome-42-2204     -
content[gtk-3-themes]     brave:gtk-3-themes              gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes  -
content[icon-themes]      brave:icon-themes               gtk-common-themes:icon-themes   -
content[sound-themes]     brave:sound-themes              gtk-common-themes:sound-themes  -
cups                      brave:cups                      cups:cups                       -
desktop                   brave:desktop                   :desktop                        -
desktop-legacy            brave:desktop-legacy            :desktop-legacy                 -
gsettings                 brave:gsettings                 :gsettings                      -
home                      brave:home                      :home                           -
joystick                  brave:joystick                  :joystick                       -
mount-observe             brave:mount-observe             -                               -
mpris                     -                               brave:mpris                     -
network                   brave:network                   :network                        -
network-bind              brave:network-bind              :network-bind                   -
network-manager           brave:network-manager           -                               -
opengl                    brave:opengl                    :opengl                         -
password-manager-service  brave:password-manager-service  -                               -
pulseaudio                brave:pulseaudio                :pulseaudio                     -
raw-usb                   brave:raw-usb                   -                               -
removable-media           brave:removable-media           :removable-media                -
screen-inhibit-control    brave:screen-inhibit-control    :screen-inhibit-control         -
system-packages-doc       brave:system-packages-doc       :system-packages-doc            -
u2f-devices               brave:u2f-devices               :u2f-devices                    -
unity7                    brave:unity7                    :unity7                         -
upower-observe            brave:upower-observe            :upower-observe                 -
wayland                   brave:wayland                   :wayland                        -
x11                       brave:x11                       :x11                            -
```